# How to exaggerate solid surface texture

Tags: texturing

I’m trying to take a model of the moon like the kind on thingiverse and make all the details of the surface more pronounced. Like make the craters deeper and the ridges higher without really changing the scale of the object whole. The moon is an imported .obj file and I’ve tried the displace modifier but it doesn’t seem to work that way.

Comment: Is the existing texture in the geometry, or is it provided by a height/displacement map?

Comment: Hi, the texture already exists in the geometry.